# Excel Alpha search for multiple rows and total the sum of different pack sizes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a deli in my store and I am trying to figure out how to add up all of what we sold in a particular day. So for instance we have Hot Wings. We sell them in 3, 6, 9 and 12. My report I get in the morning lists them as HW 3pc, HW 6pc, in different cells with the qty of the size sold then a sum how many was sold. Basically, say we sold 10 3 packs my report would be as follows. A1: HW 3 PC A2: qty 10 A3: would show 30 total. B1: HW 6pc, B2: 5 B3: 30 total and so on through the different pack size we sell.

So I would like a formula that will find all the cells that contain "HW" in them, then sum up the total sold from the total column. So 10- 3 packs (30) 5- 6 packs (30) 4-12 packs (48) the total for that day would be 108 total wings sold.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your table setup then the `SUMIFS()` formula should work for you, but only if there no other item that has "`HW` " in the name (notice the space I added, without a space it would add to the sum something like HWC [ham with cheese since you are a deli]).

The near exact formula should be (placed anywhere in your spreadsheet):

`=SUMIFS(A3:Z3, A1:Z1,"HW *")`, where Z would be the last column in your table with data.

Let me add that I surprised myself answering this, as I thought the sumifs formula only worked on columnar data.